# Relationship fields not showing up in FastAPI response

Tags: fastapi

I have the following schema:

```
class UserBase(SQLModel):
  username: str

class User(UserBase, table=True):
  id: int | None = Field(primary_key=True)
  channels: list['Channel'] = Relationship(back_populates='participants', sa_relationship_kwargs={'lazy': 'subquery'})

class UserOutput(UserBase):
  id: int
  channels: list['Channel']
```

I have an endpoint to read all users in the system.

```
@router.get('/user', response_model=??)
def read_users(...):
   return all_users(...)
```

Now, if `response_model = User`, there will be no `channels` field in the response, however, when `response_model = UserOutput`, `channels` will be set and contain the right data. Why is that?

Comment: As far as I can tell your schemas are those for ORM, while `response_model=` requires `pydantic` schemas. There are no such concepts as `Relationship` in `pydantic` schemes. You just need to draw up the correct `pydantic` scheme and specify it.

Comment: The value for the `channels` property will be `list[Channel]` for the instance that is returned from the router function. What does it matter what the value for that field is at the class level? - considering that it's functional with `UserOutput`.

Comment: The difference is that your classes are inherited from the `SQLModel`, and the `response_model` takes the `Base` class from the `pydantic`

Comment: What do you mean "takes" the `Base` class as pydantic? - "accepts"?
It's already working with the `SQLModel` instances..

Comment: I don't know which ORM you use, but it's good practice to separate database models from data validation models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because SQLModel modifies the way fields are collected so that `Relationship` is not recognized as a field. If you think about it, it makes sense from ORM point of view, because this is not a real model field.

Try this example:

with Pydantic:

```python
class A(BaseModel):
   a: list = Relationship()
```

```
>>> A()
A(a=RelationshipInfo())
>>> A.__fields__
{'a': ModelField(name='a', type=list, required=False, default=RelationshipInfo())}
```

with SQLModel:

```python
class B(SQLModel):
   a: list = Relationship()
```

```
>>> B()
B()
>>> B.__fields__
{}
```

Comment: Enlightening answer!